# Prevent SD card to be used in another Raspberry pi 2B

Tags: raspberry-pi2

I am wondering is there any way to use SD card in only one raspberry pi. 
For my project I want to be sure that no one will use the SD card in another raspberry pi.

So I decide to set password on Raspberry pi but I don't know how ?
Is there any other way to prevent this kind of actions ?

Comment: You want to prevent the use of the SD card itself or just the data on the SD card?  If just the data, could you simply encrypt it?  Or is this the operating system?

Comment: It has operating system on it and files that used in project